# SQL Oracle, case statement returning no data

Tags: sql, oracle, count, case

I have ran the following script that retrieves data related to a marketing campaign. It calculates the number of emails sent, opened, and unopened within specific time frames, and groups the data by fiscal week. It also joins data from different tables related to transactions, products, and time.  However for the 2 month case queries only it generates counts of 0 but when I manually look there is data there.

```
SELECT /*+ parallel(32) */
       fiscal_wk_idnt,
       SUM(t_email_sent2) AS sent,
       SUM(t_email_opened) AS opened,
       SUM(t_email_sent2) - SUM(t_email_opened) AS unopened,
       COUNT(CASE
               WHEN t_email_opened = 0 AND
                    t.transaction_dt_key >= mc.received_dt_key - 30 THEN
                mc.contact_key
             END) AS Unopen_Shop_1_Month,
       COUNT(CASE
               WHEN t_email_opened = 1 AND
                    t.transaction_dt_key >= mc.received_dt_key - 30 THEN
                mc.contact_key
             END) AS Open_Shop_1_Month,
       COUNT(CASE
               WHEN t_email_opened = 0 AND
                    t.transaction_dt_key BETWEEN mc.received_dt_key - 60 AND
                    mc.received_dt_key - 30 THEN
                mc.contact_key
             END) AS Unopen_Shop_2_Month,
       COUNT(CASE
               WHEN t_email_opened = 1 AND
                    t.transaction_dt_key BETWEEN mc.received_dt_key - 60 AND
                    mc.received_dt_key - 30 THEN
                mc.contact_key
             END) AS Open_Shop_2_Month,
       COUNT(CASE
               WHEN t_email_opened = 0 AND
                    t.transaction_dt_key BETWEEN mc.received_dt_key - 90 AND
                    mc.received_dt_key - 60 THEN
                mc.contact_key
             END) AS Unopen_Shop_3_Month,
       COUNT(CASE
               WHEN t_email_opened = 1 AND
                    t.transaction_dt_key BETWEEN mc.received_dt_key - 90 AND
                    mc.received_dt_key - 60 THEN
                mc.contact_key
             END) AS Open_Shop_3_Month
  FROM mfr_camps mc
  LEFT JOIN crm_target.b_transaction t
    ON mc.contact_key = t.contact_key
   AND mc.bu_key = t.bu_key
  JOIN crm_target.b_product pro
    ON t.product_key = pro.product_key
  JOIN crm_target.b_time DT
    ON mc.received_dt_key = dt.date_key
 WHERE t.transaction_type_name = 'Item'
   AND t.bu_key = '16'
 GROUP BY fiscal_wk_idnt;
```

Comment: first red flag is you are doing a left join to T but then filtering on T columns.